# Accessing Web Services using IPv6

Tags: asp.net, windows, networking, windows-server-2008, ipv6

I have a box which has both IPv4 (resolved via domain controller) and IPv6 enabled. Is it possible to access the webservices (configured using IIS) using LinkLocal address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible (probably it it) but it is very inconvenient as you'll have to specify the link identifier every time. So your address will look like

```
http://[fe80::1234:abcd%8]/
```

And because you cannot put the interface number or name in DNS (they are specific to the client and the local link anyway) the user has to know the interface id and type in the address every time.

So even if possible it's not really usable.

Comment: What's the right way to expose the EndPoints when working in a dual stack machine (server)

Comment: Get a normal IPv6 prefix (either from your ISP (PA), a Provider Independent (PI) block, or generate Unique Local Addresses (ULA)) and then number your devices with those addresses.

Comment: When you get IPv6 addresses you'll probably get a /48 (48 bits are fixed, the remaining 80 bits are yours to define). Unless you really know what you are doing you'll assign /64 prefixes to your networks. You might want to take a look at http://www.surfnet.nl/en/nieuws/Pages/IPv6numberplan.aspx for advice on how to make an addressing plan.